# Viewing varnish cache miss urls along with the backend IP

Tags: varnish, varnish-4

I am using round-robin director in my vcl. I want to see all the cache miss urls along with the backend IP. Right now doing `sudo varnishtop -i BereqURL` it is only showing the urls not the backend ip where it is going

```
    54.42 BereqURL       /catalog/v1/sizechart/keys  
   152.29 BereqURL       /catalog/v1/products/keys/
   152.17 BereqURL       /catalog/v1/bundles/stc/ids/
   145.92 BereqURL       /catalog/v1/bundles/stl/ids/
```

Is there a way I can also view the backend IPs along with the above output?

I am using vcl 4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Off the top of my head, maybe something like the following would help? Might not be the perfect solution, but may give you a better idea of which backend is getting called.

**root@cmh4:~# varnishlog | grep -i 'BereqURL\|BackendOpen'**

Output from one of my Varnish servers (My bereqURL changed though):

```
-   BereqURL       /catalog/v1/products/keys/
-   BackendOpen    770 8d2ea39e-e442-4fa3-a1bc-789eed3b9b98.dfw3 10.10.10.3 8080 10.10.10.1 37842
-   BereqURL       /id?at-xt=4dd2316d36ca2dda,0
-   BackendOpen    799 8d2ea39e-e442-4fa3-a1bc-789eed3b9b98.cmh4 10.10.10.1 8080 10.10.10.1 39065
-   BereqURL       /catalog/v1/bundles/stc/ids/
-   BackendOpen    801 8d2ea39e-e442-4fa3-a1bc-789eed3b9b98.cmh2 10.10.10.2 8080 10.10.10.1 44325
-   BereqURL       /catalog/v1/bundles/stl/ids/
-   BackendOpen    788 8d2ea39e-e442-4fa3-a1bc-789eed3b9b98.cmh2 10.10.10.2 8080 10.10.10.1 44322
```

Comment: Here `BackendOpen` is for the `BereqURL` in the preceding line?

Comment: yep! That is correct. You will have the BereqURL followed by BackendOpen. The grep is filtering down to just the two. You could do something like grep -A 5 -B 5 if you want to see more lines.